# Installing Epson Workforce 2650

Tags: epson

So far I have not found an easy way to install the workforce 2650 to ubuntu.  I have found every other epson cupps and ppd file but not for this one.  Where is it and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Epson provides a [driver for Epson WF-2650](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EL&CN2=&DSCMI=45427&DSCCHK=d512a9fe608c34b7ac3c0e6b09bbca76534f9337) (.deb).

Note
*In order to install this driver, you need to install LSB package (version 3.2 or later) beforehand.*

`sudo apt install lsb`

[Openprinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WF-2650_Series) also provides an installable .deb and details for `escpr` aswell
(32bit/64bit),
along with a detailed [How to install driver packages](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/Database/DriverPackages) article.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/635519/246201) are answers from users with Epson WF-XXXX driver installing problem, who in-short describe the whole procedure.

PS.
Noticing that this is a Cloud Ready printer you might be interested in [CUPS Cloud Print](https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/cups-cloud-print/).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing printer-driver-escpr, it should support your printer according to [Openprinting](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-escpr).

> sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr