# Need driver for Epson WF 3520

Tags: printing, epson

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm new to Ubuntu.

I cannot find a Linux driver for all-in-one printer Epson 3520.

All answers already posted are from 2014 or earlier. Some seem to indicate that a driver is available or that another Epson driver can be substituted.

Please assist if you can, please explain in as simple terms as possible.

Comment: The driver is available here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: If you are new to ubuntu, you perhaps need to know you need what is called a debian package; when I look, I see your 3520 has a full-feature driver available from here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=18777&DSCCHK=8f035f217059c5d9fa3cff68230cf71c41e74b71 and if you have 64bit ubuntu, you need the epson-inkjet-printer-201212w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and when to click to download it, the system should offer SAVE or OPEN: if you select OPEN, then gdebi installer should offer to install the package: so accept that; it will ask for your sudo password

Comment: Following the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/635519/723995 worked for me: just install the `printer-driver-escpr` package and Ubuntu should be able to detect the correct driver.